# Help identifying Turkish dessert

Tags: cake, milk, dessert, food-identification

[image: It was really good!!]

Anyone familiar with Turkish cuisine know what this is? I had this in Istanbul. All I could gather from the owner was that it is made of milk.

The texture was like a very moist cake. The taste was milky and sweet (but not very sweet). That is definitely raspberry jelly on top.

Comment: It looks like a piece of tres leche cake. Are you familiar with this? Do you know if it is Turkish, or ifthey just happen to serve it in Turkey (too)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like [Trileçe](http://www.culinarybackstreets.com/istanbul/2014/trilece/) which is indeed a Turkish take on tres leches:

> Trileçe’s heritage is a lot more complicated than that of the éclair. Chasing down the elusive origins of this cake – a Balkan cousin of the Latin American classic tres leches – leads to a deep, dark, global rabbit hole.

And it's certainly got milk in it!

> At Köfteci Arnavut they claim to mix kaymak, the heavy cream of water buffalo milk, and cow’s milk together for the characteristic soak given to the cake. At Baltepe Pastanesi, İdris Beğiroğlu called his recipe a secret but admitted that there was plenty of krem şanti, whipping cream, in there. Tuğra’s menu lists it as a cake of three milks – cow’s, goat’s and sheep’s.

[image: Trileçe]

Comment: Just read about tres leches, looks like you got it!